# Web Server for my device on the .NET Micro Framework

Tags: webserver, .net-micro-framework

I want to have a Web Server as an interface for users to tweak my device.  The device is being written in the .NET Micro Framework.

I can write my own Web Server in C# that serves static pages, it's not difficult.  But I am looking for a Web Server that supports some type of server side technology, like ASP.NET or PHP, so that from there I could mess with my hardware settings.  Is there either a commercial offering or a free one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the HttpServer class inside the .NET MF Toolkit at http://www.mftoolkit.net/.

Comment: But would I have to hand code everything? It would be quite different from the traditional style of web development, correct? I was hoping that a 3rd party device maker would ship something with some type of well-known server-side technology already on board